# Why am I not able to post my answer?

Tags: support, answers, blocklist

I tried to answer one question as I am unable to post comments, and I'm getting this weird error message:

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
>   Sorry, posts can't contain that content.

What is the reason for this message? I had just added the text of my reply with one link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've entered something that matches our blacklist. Try finding the original source of the link, or using a different link.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Will do as you suggested.